# API controller accepting a collection of Guids - an empty Guid is received when no parameter value is passed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET API controller which looks like this:

```
 [HttpGet, Route("endpoint")]
 public async Task GetValues([FromUri] IReadOnlyCollection<Guid> ids)
```

When I call this endpoint using this URI:

```
'http://localhost:56132/api/controllers/endpoint?ids='
```

and then debug the collection received, it actually contains one entry which is an empty `Guid`. I would have expected the collection to be empty in this case. Why does it work like that? Is there anything I can do so that it doesn't add this empty `Guid` to the collection?

Comment: Maybe it's because in your URI, you have this -> `ids=`.

Comment: It behaves exactly the same if you call it with 'http://localhost:56132/api/controllers/endpoint?ids'

Comment: In that case `ids` is `null`. However, the point is that if no value is supplied why does it add an empty Guid to the list?

Comment: The why is because GUID is a reference type and reference types are not nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET is doing as you're telling it: you're providing one element with no value. You've specified your collection as `<Guid>`, a value type that cannot be null so you're getting the default value for your single element, which is Guid.Empty

If you supply two parameters with no value, you'll get two elements in your collection, with Guid.Empty as the value:

```
localhost:56132/api/controllers/endpoint?ids=&ids=
```

[image]

> Is there anything I can do so that it doesn't add this empty Guid to the collection?

If you want a collection with no elements, specify no elements:

```
localhost:56132/api/controllers/endpoint?
```

[image]

If you want a collection of 1 null value, use a type that is nullable rather than `Guid`, such as `Guid?`:

[image]

Comment: That's a very good explanation and it makes sense. Thanks a lot!